# how to create filter fields in suitelet script?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to create custom filter fields using suitelet script. I tried to create those using select type field, but not getting output like proper filter. Is there any way to create custom filter field in suitelet? Please Help!

Below is my code:

How to get proper custom filter field group and fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add borders to the field group :- like this

```
    var tableField = form.addField({
                        id: 'custpage_table_field',
                        type: N_server.FieldType.INLINEHTML,
                        label: ' '
                    });
              
              var location_ ="location";   // create and set your variable 
              var htmlitem ="item";

                   htmlTable = '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
                        '<html>' +
                        '  ' +
                        '<head>' +
                        '</head>' +
                        '  ' +
                        '<body>' +
                        '    <div id="wrapper">' +
                        '  ' +
                        '        <table border=1 id="table_detail" ' +
                        '            text-align =center cellpadding=8>' +
                        '  ' +
                        '   <thead>'+
                        '            <tr>' +
                         <th height="50" bgcolor="#b8b2b2" font-size:70px   font-weight: bold text-align: center><b>ITEM</b></th>' +
                        '                <th height="50" bgcolor="#b8b2b2" font-size:70px   font-weight: bold text-align: center><b>LOCATION</b></th>' +
</tr>' +
'            <tr>' +
 <td >' + htmlitem + '</td>' +
                            '                <td class = "location">' + location_ + '</td>' +
</tr>'
                        '</thead>'+
                        '       </tbody>'+
                        '        </table>' +
                        '    </div>' +
                        '</body>' +
                        '  ' +
                        '</html>';
           
         tableField.defaultValue = htmlTable;
```

I hope it will give you an idea.

**If it does help you please vote 1 for my all answer and mark as green as relevant.**

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **options** for your selections. Like this:-

```
var selectField = form.addField({
    id : 'custpage_selectfield',
    type : serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
    label : 'Select'
});

selectField.addSelectOption({
    value : '',
    text : ''
});

selectField.addSelectOption({
    value : 'a',     
    text : 'Albert'
});

selectField.addSelectOption({
    value : 'b',
    text : 'robert'
});
```

And then **You need to call client script for its execution on every select using field changed function.**

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for response! I want to push subsidiary search values to subsidiary filter field. how it can be done?

Comment: @MairaS  I have added one more answer for this.

Comment: thanks Suitestar! can we add border and collapse and expand option to field group?
like, for example sales order list page filter

Comment: Adding border is possible only using Inline html type field. if you want you can create html type field and insert all the other fields to that html field.

Comment: Can you give sample code here?

Answer (score 0):

In above answer, can use add option for your **created filter field(Select)** in search results while running your search. Like this:-

```
searchObj.run().each(function (result) {
                                // .run().each has a limit of 4,000 results
                                var docNo = result.getValue("tranid");
                                var intId = result.getValue("internalid");
                                
    
                                selectField.addSelectOption({
                                    value : intId,
                                    text : docNo,
                                    isSelected:false
                                });
                             return true;
                            }
```

I hope it will help you for your comment.

If it does help you please vote 1 for the answer for future reference.

Thanks,